# Warning: fopen(FILE): failed to open stream: No error in CURRENT FILE

Tags: php, fopen

I recently encountered a strange error while creating a super-simple "admin page" for a website I'm currently making. Since I'm relatively new to this, I encountered quite a bunch of errors, but eventually fixed them all, except for one.

The part of the code used to create a new file looks like this :

```
$message = '"' . $file_location . $file_name . '" successfully created.';
$file = fopen($file_location . $file_name, 'w+');
if ($file) {
    fwrite($file, $file_content);
    if (fwrite($file, $file_content)) {
        fclose($file);
    }
    else {
        $message = 'ERROR : File contents could not be written in "' . $file_location . $file_name . '" .';
    }
}
else {
    $message = 'ERROR : Could not create "' . $file_location . $file_name . '" .';
}
```

For example,

- `$file_location` could be `/some/path/`
- `$file_name` could be `file.php`
- `$file_content` could be `Bap a doo bap, I teach you how to buy a CANOEEE !!1`

(please note I am using `WAMP` with a `virtual host`, so the usage of absolute paths is intended)

For some reason I didn't understand, it gave me the following error code :

```
Warning: fopen(/path/to/new-file.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\path\to\current-file.php on line XXX
```

At first, I just thought this was another one of my stupid mistakes, but after checking the code multiple times and thinking about what the problem could be, I just couldn't manage to figure it out.

I then decided to create another file containing only the problematic code :

```
<?php
    $file_name = test.php
    $file_location = /file/location/
    file = fopen($file_location . $file_name, 'w+')
?>
```

Which only gave me the same error one more, so I decided to strip the code to the absolute basics, while also using the `include` function I had already used, just to check if that was still working :

```
<?php
    $include('file.php')
    fopen('file.php, 'w+')
?>
```

(keep in mind I'd created another `file.php` file in the `root`)

While the `include` function DID work, I got the following error which basically made me abandon trying to solve the issue :

```
Warning: fopen(file.php): failed to open stream: No error in C:\path\to\file.php on line XXX
```

I've looked all around the WEB, but can't find ANYTHING. This basically makes me unable to create/modify ANY FILE with `PHP`.

Comment: the first Warning says "no such file or directory" which means the path is wrong :)

Comment: Strings must be quoted, $foo = "test.php", not $foo = test.php.  PHP will likely reference the system root if you use "/path/here".  You probably want the server's DOCUMENT_ROOT, which you can get from a server variable on many servers ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).

Comment: You also `fwrite()` twice.

Comment: Use absolute path, echo the file path properly. Also you can have a check before you do any fopen stating `if(file_exists($file_location)) { //do things } else { echo 'Invalid path ' . $file_location; }`

Comment: The last suggestion on top of those of everyone else is to a). Check the server or php_errors log files for errors and b). _always_ work with PHP in "dev mode" - that is: modifying php.ini with error_reporting E_ALL and display_errors On. Without these enabled in your dev-env, you're going to miss a heck of a lot of valuable debugging information. FYI you can skip all the fxxx() functions and ue file_put_contents() and file_get_contents() respectively. You'll still need to use those in conjunction with file_exists() as suggested by @Dharam

Comment: @niceman  I know, but I checked MANY times and the path IS right, this being wrong is probably related to the `No error` warning. @Kkinsey I usually both things you mentioned, but I seem to have forgotten this time. Sadly, this doesn't solve the issue :'( . @JuliePelletier I didn't, the second time I use it as a condition. @Dharam I do check the path exists (at least I hope so) with `if ($file)` which will be `TRUE` unless it is specifically set to `FALSE` by the line above. @theruss for now, I host this website on my computer, so I don't think I need to do anything you've said. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Tristan - `if($file)` will not do any check for you weather file exists or not. Your fopen function itself is giving the error. You must use `if(file_exists($file_location . $file_name))` before the `fopen` line to ensure that the path is correct.

Comment: @Dharam I just checked again on the `PHP` manual about `fopen()`, and if I understand correctly, I could replace what you proposed me to do with `$file = @fopen($file_location . $file_name, 'w+')` (inserting the @ symbol) followed by what I did earlier. I tried doing so and it didn't show up an error message, though it didn't create the file. So I tried to do it like you proposed me to do it, and it seems to think the location doesn't exist in deed, which is really strange since this works with other functions, like `include()` for example ... What am I doing wrong ??

Comment: if you echo `$file_location . $file_name` what output it is giving? Do note that it must be an absolute path and not relative. It should be something like `/var/www/projectname/foldername/filename.php`

Comment: Just what you'd expect : `/file/path/file-name.php`. I also modified the file to use the `if(file_exists())` condition, and updated the `$message` values for different situations, and it indicates me the directory doesn't exist ... The strangest thing is that functions like `include()` DO work for the exact same directory.

Comment: is it the absolute path starting from your root directory. Ex. if in linusx it shall echo `var/www/projectname/file.php` if on windows it shall echo `C:\xampp\htdocs\project\filename.php` gave the examples to make my point clear. I hope you are not using the relative path for file writing. If it is not confidential and you are working on local, you can let us know the exact output it is giving rather than the example

Comment: Well since this code comes from a "mini admin page" for a website I set those variables myself, and if I wanted to create a new file in the root directory of the website (which is the case here), `$file_location` would be equal to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/'` and `file_name` could be anything (for example `test.php`). I use absolute path without the `C:/wamp64/www/website-name/` since I'm running this website on a virtual host, i.e. I just type in `website-name` (don't even need the `/`) in my browser's address bar to get to the website. So I use an absolute path with a vhost.

Comment: IT WORKS !!! I just tried RIGHT AFTER replying to your comment, and I don't know why, but it JUST WORKED ! It does piss me off a bit I don't know what the cause was, but I'm too happy to worry about that. Also, I don't usually say this, but thanks a lot @Dharam to help me all the way through ;)

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar problem with the exact same error message.

```
 failed to open stream: No error in C:\path\to\file.php on line XXX
```

In my case it was because I was trying to send a $_GET parameter to the file.

With includes you don't need to send $_GET parameters, the files are not executed independently, but rather the include is like a copy and paste into the parent file. All the variables I needed were already available.